# Titanium - How to get info from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, titanium

I am new to Titanium and I want to send my coordinates and the destination coordinates to google maps and get as reply the distance! How to do that? GET HTTP with Google API or is any other easier way on Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

With Titanium, there is a Google Maps API built in.  Everything you'll need to know about maps can be found [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Map-module)!